# Esperanta vorto por “bouldering”

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi demandas min ĉu ekzistas disvastiĝinta vorto por la sporto “bouldering” (kiel grimpado, sed sen ŝnuregoj kaj sekuriloj kaj nur ĝis malmultaj metroj de alteco).

La evidenta eblo estas laŭvorta traduko el la angla: “ŝtonegado”

Comment: Mi atendis ***rokogrimpadon***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respondo al la demando “Ĉu ekzistas ĝenerale akceptata esperanta traduko de *bouldering?*”, vi jam scias, estas **ne.**

Ĉar ni estas esperantistoj, la tujposta demando estas “Kiu estus oportuna traduko?”. Konsiderante, ke *bouldering* ne nepre okazas sur ŝtonegoj, sed ofte ankaŭ sur artefaritaj krutaĵoj en sportejoj ks., mi klopodus emfazi la teknikan diferencon kun tradicia montgrimpado: dum ĉi lasta postulas multan eltenemon kaj rezistokapablon, *bouldering* okazas laŭ pli malaltaj, mallongaj vojoj, kaj postulas malpli daŭran sed multe pli intensan fortostreĉon, kaj tial mi opinias, ke *basgrimpado,* laŭ propono de Kirilo en komento ĉi tie, estas tre bona.

Cetere, mi ne vere distingas inter *sporta grimpado* kaj *basgrimpado* en ajna lingvo, sed tio ŝuldiĝas al mia ekstermedieco.

Comment: Tian respondon mi atendis. Mi akceptis vian respondon ĉar ĝi estis pli frua ol la respondo de Vidamuzo.

Answer (score 1):

Ŝajnas al mi ke la plej evidenta esprimo estas la klarigo en via demando:

- malalta grimpado
- ŝton-grimpado
- senŝnura grimpado

Comment: “Malalta” eble. Sed bouldering ankaû havas pli malfacilajn prenojn ol normala grimpado. Ili malsamas en kelkaj aspektoj. “Senŝnura” malbonas ĉar homoj ankaŭ grimpas normale senŝnure, kaj tio estas tute malsama afero. "ŝton-grimpado" ankaŭ ne vere plaĉas al mi. Strangas ke laûŝajne ne ekzistas "oficiala" vorto por tio.

Comment: Do "bolderingo" se vi insistas.

Comment: Dankon por la proponoj, sed la celo de mia demando estis eltrovi ĉu ekzistas jam disvastiĝinta vorto por ĝi, ne krei novan vorton.

Comment: Por substreki mian punkton - "bolderingo" ne estas serioza propono, sed reago al la ideo ke *devas* esti vorto por bouldering. Pli bona demando estas "kio estas bouldering kaj kiel mi povas esprimi tiun ideon en Esperanto?"

Answer (score 1):

Ŝajnas, ke ankoraŭ ne ekzistas establita termino por tio en Esperanto. Mi rekomendus ekuzi **ŝtonegogrimpado**. Kompreneble, oni ne ĉiam faras ĝin sur ŝtonego, sed foje ankaŭ sur grimpomuroj, sed se ĝi fiksiĝos kiel aparta termino, tio ne vere gravas. La pli konciza **ŝtonegado** ankaŭ eblas, sed ĝi povus esti iom malpli facile komprenebla.

Comment: Mi ne komprenus la vorton _ŝtonegado_. Ankaŭ ĉe _ŝtoneggrimpado_ mi ne tuj scius, ke temas pri "bouldering" (ĉar mi ne konis la anglan vorton _boulder_), sed almenaŭ mi kaptis, ke temas pri speco de grimpado. Kial ne "basgrimpado"? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Mi samopinias kun Dario, ke *basgrimpado* laŭ propono de Cyril estas tre bona. Mi scivolas ĉu la vorto *blokogrimpado* (aŭ *blokgrimpado*) povas esti taŭga propono, kiu laŭ Vikipedio estas uzata en la hispana kaj la franca (*escalada en bloque, escalade de bloc*). Laŭdifine *bloko* estas *peza, unupeca maso de malmola materio* (ekz. bloko el petro, marmoro, ligno, ktp).

Comment: Multan dankon! Mi aparte ŝatas la vorton "blokgrimpado" ĉar ĝi sekvas la malnovan esperantan tradicion de preni ian vorton el la franca kaj meti esperantan silabon al la fino. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nudmana grimpado.  Varapado (oficiale esperantigita franca vorto).